# During an investigation, can a US law enforcement officer say something is legal if it is not?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, police, self-incrimination

When investigating something that has already happened, can a US law enforcement officer say "x is perfectly legal" to get someone to confess to having done x (which is not actually legal and someone will be prosecuted for x if they (or a co-conspirator) confess to it).

Answer (score 1):

In general, police are allowed to lie. Certain statements are taken to be self-enforcing, for example "You are under arrest" *means* that you are under arrest, "Yes" in response to "Am I free to go" is taken to mean that you are free to go and therefore if you leave, they can't beat you for attempting to escape arrest.

Comment: I think you are covering entrapment.  The question was whether an officers can trick a suspect to confessing to something that they had *already* done.

Comment: @grovkin what is it about this answer that limits it to entrapment?  It says that officers are in general allowed to lie.  That includes lies such as claiming to have incriminating evidence when they don't, which is a classic ruse to induce a confession.

Comment: @phoog the last sentence gives an example of criminal behavior which is induced, rather than confessed, because of a lie.  Inducing criminal behavior, by lying about its criminality, is classic entrapment.

Comment: @grovkin:  It seems that the person being questioned has already taken x action without any prompting by the police.   Later, he is told X action is legal by the police and admits to doing X action.   The police arrest him because X action is in fact illegal.   Entrapment would only occure if the police said "You should do X action" and the civilian then does X action on that knowledge.

Comment: @hszmv you are talking about the action which was the cause of arrest.  I am talking about the example the last sentence.  Which can be read as police are not allowed to entrap someone into resisting arrest.

Comment: An important exception exists for law enforcement officers who are also attorneys and are limited by professional ethics requirements from making intentionally false statements that non-attorney law enforcement agents could make.

Comment: @grovkin But the OP was not talking about an Entrapment scenario, but rather the scenario outlined in my first three sentances.

Comment: @hszmv exactly. if you read my 1st comment, that's what i complained about. this answer gave an example which demonstrated a situation which was different from what the OP asked about.